# Second join in LINQ Query causes no records to return

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to join three lists but for some reason the second join is causing no data to be returned.  I ultimately *do* want to "left" join this, but I'm trying to solve the problem of it not joining properly first.

My three lists:

```
var equipmentAliasList = new List<EquipmentAlias> {
    new EquipmentAlias { Alias = "100-00001"},
    new EquipmentAlias { Alias = "100-00005"},
    new EquipmentAlias { Alias = "100-00004"},
    new EquipmentAlias { Alias = "100-00003"},
    new EquipmentAlias { Alias = "100-00002"},
}

var assets = new List<Asset> {
    new Asset { AssetNum = "100-00001", LineAsset = "200-00001"},
    new Asset { AssetNum = "100-00005", LineAsset = "200-00002"},
    new Asset { AssetNum = "100-00004", LineAsset = ""},
    new Asset { AssetNum = "100-00003", LineAsset = "200-00001"},
    new Asset{ AssetNum = "100-00002", LineAsset = ""},
};

var lineAssets = new List<Asset> {
    new Asset { AssetNum = " 200-00001", IsRunning = true },
    new Asset { AssetNum = " 200-00002", IsRunning = false },
};
```

So, select all from `equipmentAliasList` join `assets` on `assetNum` and then join `lineAssets` on `asset.LineAsset equals lineAsset.AssetNum`.

Here's what I've come up with:

```
(from e in equipmentAliasList
join ma in assets on e.Alias equals ma.AssetNum
join la in lineAssets on ma.LineAsset equals la.AssetNum
select new EquipmentAlias
{
    Alias = e.Alias,
    IsPor = la.IsRunning,
}).ToList();
```

And the result should be:

```
  Alias   |   IsPor
----------|-----------
100-00001 |   true
100-00005 |   false
100-00003 |   true
```

However, the join from `assets` to `lineAssets` is causing the query to not return any results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you notice lineAssets, there are spaces in AssetNum field. Change `" 200-00001"` to `"200-00001"`

```
var lineAssets = new List<Asset> {
    new Asset { AssetNum = "200-00001", IsRunning = true },
    new Asset { AssetNum = "200-00002", IsRunning = true },
};
```

Comment: `facepalm.jpg`.  That's correct.  Can accept in 6 minutes